# Loading a Webpage from my emulator

Tags: android

In My application i want to load a webpage by ckicking a TextView. How i can do this?
Please Help.

Thank You.

Comment: bad accept ratio, try to managed it

Comment: I think you want to put Hyperlinks text and clicking on that you want to open webpage connected with that link , is it so ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to do it by webview........
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-webview-example-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Add an event to textview, 
For example, your textview is defined as textView

```java
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
        startActivity(i);
    }           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using webview you can place html anchor tag

here is an example uses html in webview

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=369